# asp classic SQL Injection

Tags: sql, asp

He estado buscando funciones en `ASP` clásico para evitar **sql Injection** y por lo que he podido ver no hay ninguna función. Si que he visto que existen en `.NET` pero no he encontrado nada para `ASP` clásico.

¿Realmente no hay ninguna?

Por ahora me he planteado crear un par de funciones que primero filtren por tipo de campo (si es numérico, fecha...), luego por tamaño determinado y por último que controle que no se introduzcan palabras como `SELECT`, `INSERT`,... y caracteres especiales **(* , = , ...)**

¿Alguna recomendación?

Comment: La recomendación es la misma que para asp.net: usar queries **parametrizados**.[Aqui](http://prepared-statement.blogspot.com.es/2006/02/asp-prepared-statements.html)  y [aqui](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/classic-asp-sql-injection-prevention-by-using-query-parameter/) tienes un par de ejemplos

Comment: Vale. Gracias. Eso también habia empezado a cambiarlo. Es que me ha tocado una página web que lleva 12 años sin realizar ninguna medida de seguridad y ya que iba a empezar a realizar modificaciones pensé en meter también la función.¿Haciendo la parametrización de las queries ya vale para evitar el sql injection?

Comment: Si,con la parametrización se evita el riesgo de sql injection practicamente. Explicar como y porqué es un poco largo, puedes echar un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6786034/579895) en ingles. Tambien hay que evitar generar queries _dinamicas_, por ejemplo, que el nombre de la tabla esté en una variable, pero en general usando queries parametrizados estás totalmente a salvo.

Comment: Vale. Muchas gracias

Comment: @sstan me parece bien. He añadido mi comentario como respuesta, no es muy completo pero al menos es mejor que la otra respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Si,existen queries parametrizados de igual manera que en asp.net. [Aqui](http://prepared-statement.blogspot.com.es/2006/02/asp-prepared-statements.html) y [aqui](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/classic-asp-sql-injection-prevention-by-using-query-parameter/) tienes un par de artículos explicando la manera de hacerlo en asp clásico.

Con la parametrización se evita el riesgo de sql injection prácticamente. Explicar cómo y porqué es un poco largo, puedes echar un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6786034/579895) en inglés. También hay que evitar generar queries dinámicas, por ejemplo, que el nombre de la tabla esté en una variable, pero en general usando queries parametrizados estás totalmente a salvo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo en si día encontré una función que lo que hace es limpiar de las cadenas o parámetros, todo lo relativo a sentencias `SQL`. De manera que paso los parámetros antes por esta función para limpiarlos

```
function clear_param(texto)

dim texto_final
    texto_final=replace(texto, "SELECT", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "‘", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "UPDATE", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "DELETE", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "DROP", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "UNION ", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "%", "&#37;")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "%00", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "%27", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "%3D", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, " TOP ", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, " GROUP ", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "=", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, ">", "&#62;")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "<", "&#60;")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "IIF", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "FROM", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, " OR ", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, " AND ", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, " IN ", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, " CHR ", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, " ASC(", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, " CurDir ", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "LEN(", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "SHELL", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "ASCII", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "SUBSTRING", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "LENGTH", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "version", "")
    texto_final=replace(texto_final, "exists", "")
    clear_param=texto_final

End function
```

Comment: Y despues tenemos el chiste de la mama que le puso a su hijo JOHNDELETE y el query le cambiaba el nombre.. esta bueno.. es peligroso..  Esta bueno, no se si es la mejor solucion...

Comment: Hoal José. Gracias por el aporte. Pero toma en cuenta que este tipo de función puede hacer más daño que bien, porque te puede dar una falsa sensación de seguridad. La realidad es que es practicamente imposible anticipar todos los keywords peligrosos, sin hablar de los nuevos keywords que pueden ir agregándose con nuevas versiones de bases de datos. Realmente, la única solución que evita el problema de inyección SQL de forma segura, tanto para hoy como para mañana, es usando consultas parametrizadas.

Comment: @gbianchi se refiere a este: [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/)